# Android location manager returns same gps coordinates every time

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, location-provider

I am creating an app to send the phones location to my server. The issue i have is that the phone gives me the exact same gps coordinates every time i start the app. When i restart it the coordinates can change, but after the first coordinate is sent it will send the same once until the app is restarted.

Code:

```
// Contructor etc

public class LocationASYNC extends AsyncTask<Activity, String, Void> {
    private MainActivity m;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Criteria c;

    public LocationASYNC(MainActivity m) {
        this.m = m;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) m
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        c = new Criteria();
        c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                3000, 0, m);
    }

// Code for finding best location provider and returning location
    private Location findBestLocation() {

            Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true));

            Log.v("location",
                    "provider: " + locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true));
            // Check if location is null
            if (location != null) {
                Log.v("location", "provider not null");
                // Test if location is more than 100 seconds old
                if (location.getTime() < (System.currentTimeMillis() - 100000)) {
                    Log.v("location", "provider is old(GPS)");
                    // Use network if location is more than 100 seconds (99% chance
                    // location will be gps)
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    // Check if network location is more then 100 seconds
                    Log.v("location", "provider: " + location.getProvider());
                    if (location.getTime() < (System.currentTimeMillis() - 100000)) {
                        // Return null if all location data is old
                        Log.v("location", "provider is old (INT)");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                // Return location if one is less than 100 seconds old
                return location;
            }
            // return null if no location is found
            return null;
        }

This is the output i get from logcat:

02-05 15:31:59.670: V/location(29659): provider: network
02-05 15:31:59.675: V/location(29659): lat: 60.3935485 lon: 5.3114676 time: 1360074627953 acc: 28.757
02-05 15:32:02.685: V/location(29659): provider: gps
02-05 15:32:02.685: V/location(29659): provider not null
02-05 15:32:02.685: V/location(29659): provider is old(GPS)
02-05 15:32:02.690: V/location(29659): provider: network
02-05 15:32:02.690: V/location(29659): lat: 60.3935485 lon: 5.3114676 time: 1360074627953 acc: 28.757
02-05 15:32:05.700: V/location(29659): provider: gps
02-05 15:32:05.700: V/location(29659): provider not null
02-05 15:32:05.705: V/location(29659): provider is old(GPS)
02-05 15:32:05.710: V/location(29659): provider: network
02-05 15:32:05.710: V/location(29659): lat: 60.3935485 lon: 5.3114676 time: 1360074627953 acc: 28.757
02-05 15:32:08.720: V/location(29659): provider: gps
02-05 15:32:08.720: V/location(29659): provider not null
02-05 15:32:08.720: V/location(29659): provider is old(GPS)
02-05 15:32:08.725: V/location(29659): provider: network
02-05 15:32:08.725: V/location(29659): provider is old (INT)
```

Latitude and longitude are the same for every log cat post, and also the time (millisec since 1980 or so.) is the same.

It seems like my app gets the location once and does not attempt to get the position again.

Comment: Which phone are you using, Samsung ?

Comment: Did you have some answer? I have the same problem.

Comment: Any update ? Did you try the solution before ?

Comment: What happens in MainActivity which is registered as location listener? The location is available there in the onLocationChanged() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if GPS is enabled on your device or if device supports GPS.